# How to send message back from client to the server via WebSocket in Laravel with Laravel WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

WebSocket allows two-way communication: the server can send messages to the browser and the browser - the client - can respond back via the same connection.

I am implementing Chat Application in Laravel 6 using:

- [Laravel Echo JavaScript Package](https://github.com/laravel/echo) (not laravel-echo-server),
- [Laravel WebSockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/)
- [pusher-js](https://npmjs.com/package/pusher-js).

I already get it worked that the server triggers events and the client listens to those events as following.

1. Install Laravel WebSockets package.

`composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets`

2. Configure `config/broadcasting.php`.

```
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => xxx,
            'secret' => xxx,
            'app_id' => xxx,
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => xxx,
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => true, 
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

3. Configure `config/websockets.php`

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => xxx,
            'name' => xxx,
            'key' => xxx,
            'secret' => xxx,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

4. Install `Pusher` server.

`composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"`

5. Set broadcasting driver to use `pusher` in `.env` file.

`BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`

6. Use `laravel-echo` and `pusher-js` on my client side.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your-pusher-key',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

7. Start WebSockets server.

`php artisan websockets:serve`

8. On the server-side, trigger events with an event class that implements `ShouldBroadcastNow` class.

`event(new MyEventClass((object)$message));`

Everything works fine. In step 8, I trigger events from the server-side.

Note that I am not using the official Pusher server, I just utilize the Pusher API implementations and `pusher-js` but point the `Laravel Echo JavaScript package` to the local `Laravel WebSockets server`, configured in step 6.

Please do not confus `Laravel Echo JavaScript package` with `laravel-echo-server` of `Socket.IO Server`. I am not using `Socket.IO Server`.

Now instead of triggering events on the server-side as shown in step 8, I want to tigger events from the client-side since WebSocket allows two-way communication. How can I do that in `Laravel` with `Laravel Echo JavaScript Package`, `Laravel WebSockets PHP package`?

Comment: Please can you link to the exact packages your using (Laravel Echo JavaScript Package, Laravel WebSockets and pusher-js).

Comment: Link to Laravel Echo JavaScript Package: https://github.com/laravel/echo

Comment: Link to Laravel WebSockets: https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/

Comment: Link to pusher-js NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pusher-js

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought you meant a completely different Laravel echo package.

Comment: yes, I meant Laravel Echo JavaScript Packpage, not that laravel-echo-server maintaining Socket,IO server.

Comment: Are you after something like this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#client-events

Comment: Yes Something like this: To broadcast client events, you may use Echo's whisper method:

`Echo.private('chat')
    .whisper('typing', {
        name: this.user.name
    });` 
To listen for client events, you may use the listenForWhisper method:

`Echo.private('chat')
    .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
        console.log(e.name);
    });`

Comment: I could see that WebSockets server did receive message from events, but client does not hear that events. I miss something.

Comment: @OConnor have you found a way to send message privately to server? Since any data sent to server from client gets received on web-sockets process, from there it has to be passed to laravel. I too had searched a lot for sending data from client to server but never found a way 

Comment: did you somehow handle this? cause I have same problem here!!!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this documentation: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events#triggering-client-events

According to pusher documentation, Initialize your front end using this

```
 this.echo = new Pusher('mykey', {
    wsHost: 'localhost',
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
  });
```

use this to trigger your event

```
var channel = this.echo.subscribe("private-channel");
channel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", () => {
var triggered = channel.trigger("client-someEventName", {
   your: "data",
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After having initialized Echo, you need to listen on a certain channel within your frontend.  I will show some Vue code, but modify accordingly:

Vue File

```
export default {
    methods: {
        sendCommand(command) {
            axios.post('/api/command', { 'command': command })
            .then((res) => {
                //
            })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        Echo.channel('xxx')
        .listen('.weight-change', (e) => {
            this.weight = e.weight
        })
    }
}
```

In here, you can see that all the incoming messages are captured on the listen portion of the code and sending a new message is done with an api route on the backend that sends them to the Echo channel.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: This is the same as step 8 I have done, With `axios.post('/api/command')`, you make an API call to the server to trigger events. Thus events are being triggered on the server-side. I am looking for solution to trigger events on the client-side. When you invoke `sendCommand(command)` method on the client-side within a VueJs component that call `axios.post()` does not mean you trigger events on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that may face this issue.

You no need echo and should instantiate from the Pusher directly

```
const my_pusher = new Pusher("APP_KEY", {
        cluster: 'mt1',
        wsHost: window.location.hostname,
        wsPort: 6001,
        forceTLS: false,
        disableStats: true,
    });
```

And to send message to the server:

```
my_pusher.send_event('EVENT_NAME',{'ANYTHING':'YOU_WANT'})
```

Comment: You are not going to hit the server with this, its only client side. Therefor you cant do any validation or anything on the data.

Comment: @MichaelAndersen By this code, client side can send any event to server. Any validation can be provided in server side

Answer (score 0):

I might be incorrect, but I don't believe you can push to Pusher with their `pusher-js` package. That's what the `pusher-php-server` composer package is for.

There may be a node package for this, but why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Just use axios or a Vuex action to post to one of your routes to fire your event and then let Echo pick up the response.

You don't even need to create a controller, just use a route closure and fire your event. Axios or Vuex will both return a Promise so you can manage wait for a response in your component or your Vuex action.

I could understand if you were trying to implement a different type of driver to Broadcast with like RabbitMQ or Rachet or something, but it's designed to be a circular loop of sorts, hit your endpoint from js, fire the event from PHP, let Pusher/or websockets do it's thing, receive your broadcast back in js.

Comment: This is not the way websockets are working. There is already a ws connection. Why should i send a post request again and again to my backend?